# Difference between Visa Withdrawn, refusal, and rejection

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I have certain questions (applicable to Schengen and UK visas), I tried looking for them here but couldn't understand the difference between these terminologies:

1. How is Visa withdrawn (after the biometrics) treated, do they consider the withdrawn application for future applications?
2. Is visa refusal the same as rejection?
3. Is cancellation the same as withdrawn?
4. Is it necessary to mention in future applications that one has previously withdrawn the application for any country(due to any reason)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[uk-visas](/questions/tagged/uk-visas)

> Is Visa refusal the same as rejection?

No, a rejection is declared due issues outside of the applicants' control like

> the applicant must meet an age requirement to apply on a route and they are not young or old enough

> the applicant must have been in the UK/outside the UK when they made their application, and they were not

This is called a *Validity rejection*, this is **not** the same as a refusal and will not impact your file in any shape or form

An application can also be voided

> An application is void when it where it would not be possible to grant the applicant the permission for which they applied. For example:
>
> an application for limited leave to enter/remain (permission to enter/stay) made by a person who already has indefinite leave to enter or remain (settlement)

This also applies if the applicant dies before the application is adjudicated.

> Is cancellation the same as Withdrawn?

Cancellation is the action of rendering an **existing** permission to stay/enter in the UK invalid

This is usually done when you make another application, but that can also be at all time.

The grounds for cancellation are laid out in Part 9 of the Immigration rules, are many and range from :

> Making of false representations, submission of false documents or false information and failure to disclose relevant facts in relation to, or in support of an application

to

> Change of job or lower salary rate

> How is Visa Withdrawn(after the biometrics) treated, do they consider the withdrawn application for future applications?

If they suspect that you lied on your application or any other reasons , they can deny your withdrawal and still adjudicate your case

> The most common reason to refuse to accept a withdrawal request from an applicant and decide an application is where there is a suspicion that deception has been exercised by the applicant. For example, if the applicant has knowingly submitted fraudulent documents.

In this case, the visa becomes refused and you must report a **refused** visa everywhere

> Is it necessary to mention in future applications that one has previously withdrawn the application for any country(due to any reason)?

If your withdrawal is accepted, your application will not be adjudicated and it's **very unlikely** that you will have to mention the withdrawn application

---

- [Caseworker guidance for withdrawals](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/specified-application-forms-and-procedures/validation-variation-voiding-and-withdrawal-of-applications-accessible)
- [Caseworker guidance for cancellations](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1023269/Cancellation_and_Curtailment_of_permission.pdf)

Comment: so just a note mentioning "I had filed an application at XYZ or UK country but withdrew it" at the end would suffice? or no need to mention any withdrawn application. I get it Refusal you have to mention, but there is no question regarding withdrawal in either UK or Canada form. Will it be considered deliberately hiding something? Or just be truthful to only the questions asked in the form and provide the supporting documents.

Answer (score 4):

Withdrawal is triggered by you, the applicant.
Refusal and rejections are two words for the same thing, and are triggered by the issuing authority.

A withdrawal therefore is voluntary, you deciding you no longer want to travel and thus no longer need the visa. It's unlikely to influence future applications afaik.

A rejection/refusal is the result of the issuing authority deciding you're not eligible to receive a visa based on the information you provided. It very well may influence future applications, especially as it may trigger even more scrutiny on those future applications.

Both of course mean you now are not getting a visa and won't be allowed to travel (and if you do will be turned back at the border, or more likely at checkin at your departure airport).

Comment: I agree that “withdrawal” when discussing visas usually means what this answer says — but that’s generally described as withdrawal of the *application*, not of the visa.  If some sources really talk about withdrawal of a *visa*, then I could imagine it meaning either this, or cancellation of a visa by the issuing country.

Comment: In some countries (e.g. UK and Canada), an application may be rejected (sent back) for incompleteness or ineligibility to *submit*; such applications are not considered to have been refused: they are simply never processed on merits.

Answer (score 3):

[schengen-visas](/questions/tagged/schengen-visas)

> 1. How is Visa Withdrawn (after the biometrics) treated, do they consider the withdrawn application for future applications?

A **withdrawn** application (and the reason why it was withdrawn) will remain in the **Visa Information System** (VIS). It can therefore be seen during any future application.

> 2. Is Visa refusal the same as rejection?

Yes. The Schengen Visa Code uses the term **refusal**.

> 3. Is cancellation the same as Withdrawn?

Only when the cancellation (revocation, revoking) is at the request of the visa holder.

> 4. Is it necessary to mention in future applications that one has previously withdrawn the application for any country(due to any reason)?

For a withdrawn application, as understood by the Schengen Visa Code, no.

But this may depend on the interpretation of the country in question.

---

If an application is considered **inadmissible** then:

- the application form and any documents submitted by the applicant will be returned
- the collected biometric data will be destroyed
- the visa fee will be reimbursed
- the application will not be examined
- (it is not a refusal/rejection)

If the application is considered **admissible**, then the application data will be entered into the VIS system and examined.

If an **admissible** application has been **withdrawn**, no decision can be made

- the visa **has not** been issued or refused (rejected)

If an **issued** visa has been **annulled**

- then the visa has been **refused**

This is **not** automaticlly the case when an issued visa has been **revoked** (canceled).

When the visa has been *revoked* at the request of the visa holder, then it would have the same status as an application that has been **withdrawn**.

---

> **Schengen Visa Code**:
>
> **Article 23 (Decision on the application)**
> ...
> 4. **Unless the application has been *withdrawn***, a decision shall be taken to:
> (a) **issue** a uniform visa in accordance with Article 24;
> ...
> (c) **refuse** a visa in accordance with Article 32.
> ...
> **Article 34 (Annulment and revocation)**
>
> 1. A visa shall be **annulled** where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it were not met at the time when it was issued, ...
> 2. A visa shall be **revoked** where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it are no longer met. ...
> 3. A visa may be *revoked* at the **request of the visa holder**. ...
>    ...

Comment: so withdrawn application is not the same as a refusal? and one has to mention along with the reason in the future application, does it have any negative impact just like the refusal?

Comment: @The_Scan_Master You give the reason when withdrawning the application (Had a car accident and cannot undertake the trip) and it will be noted in the VIS system. Why should such a reason (or any other personal reason) have a side effect?

Comment: @MarkJohnson sometimes some authorities asks you if you'd like to withdraw your application in cases where a visa can't be granted. Perhaps The_Scan_Master is talking about this?

Comment: @user253751 That is something that you should ask The_Scan_Master.

Comment: A rejection **is not the same** as a refusal. A rejection is applied when, for ex. the consulate you're applying to is not the right one

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The term used in the Visa Code for this is **inadmissible**. The term *rejection* is not used at all, probably to avoid misunderstandings.